# Can't Change PHP Switch Case URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, switch-statement

This has been bothering me for awhile. I have some pages on my website that use PHP switch cases to change the content of the page. The problem I'm having is that the URLs for these pages are not very SEO friendly.

I want to change 
this:

`http://www.abcprintingink.com/printing.php?page=print-and-mail`

to this:

`http://www.abcprintingink.com/printing.php/print-and-mail` or better

`http://www.abcprintingink.com/printing/print-and-mail`

I've tried .htaccess and nothing works. Here is what I've tried in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^web.php/([^-]*)$ /web.php?page=$1 [QSA]

#RewriteRule ^/web.php/?page\=(.*)$ /web.php?page=$1 [l]

RewriteRule ^web.php/(.*)$ /web.php?page=$1 [l]

RewriteRule ^web.php/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ web.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Other commands in .htaccess work so I know it's not the file or the webserver.

This is the switch statement in printing.php

```
<?php
        /* SEO Switch Statements */
        $pagename = "printing";
        $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["page"]);

        switch ($page) {
case 'print-and-mail':
                $page_title = 'page title';
                $page_description = 'page desc';
                $page_nav_active = 'print-and-mail';
                $page_content_copy = 'page text';
                $template_slider_image = 'image';
                break;
}
?>
```

Also, this is the script behind the menus that link the pages.

```
    <?php $menu=count($navigation); for ($i=0; $i<$menu; $i++) 
{ echo '<div><li class="navigation"><a href="?page='.$navigation[$i].'">'
.$replaced = str_replace("-", " ", $navigation[$i]).'</a></li></div>'; } ?>
```

Comment: Are you saying that those links don't work (404 presumably) or that they do work and PHP's switch statement isn't receiveing the values in the GET now? (So the page shows wrong content)?

Comment: Oh no, they work alright. It's just the URLs display like "webpage.php?page=content-page" and I can't get them to display differently regardless of a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file.

Comment: if it helps I have this code in the navigation menu            <?php $menu=count($navigation);
      for ($i=0;  $i<$menu; $i++) {
       echo '<div><li class="navigation"><a href="?page='.$navigation[$i].'">'.$replaced = str_replace("-", " ", $navigation[$i]).'</a></li></div>';
     } ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

## 301 redirect, http://www.abcprintingink.com/printing.php?page=print-and-mail
## to http://www.abcprintingink.com/printing/print-and-mail
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^printing\.php$ /printing/%1? [R=301,L]

## makes /printing/print-and-mail actually work
RewriteRule ^printing/(.*)$ /printing\.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work. I put that rewrite rule in and even when I type the url in directly it returns a 404 error.

Comment: @SpyderTech do you have a file called printing.php in your root web folder?

Comment: yes I do and that is the file that holds the switch case statements

Comment: Show us that switch statement in your question.

Comment: I put a portion of the switch statement in the question, along with the code that goes behind the menu to link the pages together.

Comment: @SpyderTech ok try the htaccess I just modified in my post

Comment: it's very close. It now goes to the index page rather than throwing a 404 error. Looks like I'll need to find a way to keep it on the printing.php page.

Comment: Lol looks like I kept my test path in there, just modify it like i just did.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility you could try is sending all information to a core file such as index.php and then serving the correct data from their

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Parse the URL in index.php and then either bring in the data via include statements and populate the $_GET array or call the templates and populate the variables from the database.

This would be the way I would do it - probably after spending weeks of trying to get the regular expression correct.
Mainly because regular expressions and htaccess rarely do what I want them to do (my own limitation rather than that of regex).

Comment: the .htaccess rewrite option worked, but I did think about parsing the url. Thank you.